# Use custom font to the Canvas text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

In my code I can introduce text to the canvas and I can also change the color and the location. I tried to put a custom font for the text input but it's not working(it remains the standard one which I think is Arial). Can you please help me with this one? This is my JsFiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/x6dqox1t/  .Thank you for your time.

**Here is my CSS code:**

```
#canvas3 {
 border: 2px dotted black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: absolute;
}

#canvas4 {
 border: 2px dotted black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: absolute;
}

.green {
 border: 0.1px solid #CCC;
 margin: 1px;
 zoom: 3;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 22.5px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: #009933;
}

.green:hover,
.green:active,
.green:focus {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #136a65;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
  transition: all 250ms linear;
 }

 .red {
   border: 0.1px solid #CCC;
   margin: 1px;
   zoom: 3;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 22.5px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: #ff0000;
  }

  .red:hover,
  .red:active,
  .red:focus {
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
   opacity: 0.7;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #136a65;
   -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
   transition: all 250ms linear;
  }


 .orange {
  border: 0.1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 1px;
  zoom: 3;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 22.5px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
 }

 .orange:hover,
 .orange:active,
 .orange:focus {
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
   opacity: 0.7;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #136a65;
   -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
   transition: all 250ms linear;
   }

  @font-face {
   font-family: 'KulminoituvaRegular';
   src: url('http://www.miketaylr.com/f/kulminoituva.ttf');
  }
```

**Here is my JAVASCRIPT code:**

```
 var canvas3 = document.getElementById("canvas3");
    var ctx3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");

    ctx3.font = " bold 90px KulminoituvaRegular";
    ctx3.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx3.textAlign = "center";

    var $text3 = document.getElementById("sourceText3");

    $text3.onkeyup = function(e) {
      redrawTextsCan3();
    }

    function redrawTextsCan3() {
      ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, canvas3.width, canvas3.height);
      wrapText(ctx3, $text3.value, 66.5, 82, "KulminoituvaRegular");
    }

    function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, fontSize, fontFace) {
      var words = text.split(' ');
      var line = '';
      var lineHeight = fontSize;

      context.font = fontSize + " " + fontFace;

      for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
        var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
        var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
        var testWidth = metrics.width;
        if (testWidth > maxWidth) {
          context.fillText(line, x, y);
          line = words[n] + ' ';
          y += lineHeight;
        } else {
          line = testLine;
        }
      }
      context.fillText(line, x, y);
      return (y);
    }

    var loc = document.getElementById("canvas3");
    var ctxx = loc.getContext("2d");

    function path3(v2) {
      switch (v2) {
        // top: 103px; left: 210px
        case "rightabove":
          loc.style.top = "93px";
          loc.style.left = "130px";
          loc.style.position = "absolute";
          break;

        case "rightbelow":
          loc.style.top = "133px";
          loc.style.left = "130px";
          loc.style.position = "absolute";
          break;

        case "left":
          loc.style.top = "113px";
          loc.style.left = "400px";
          loc.style.position = "absolute";
          break;

        case "center":
          loc.style.top = "113px";
          loc.style.left = "173px";
          loc.style.position = "absolute";
          break;
      }
      redrawTextsCan3();
    }


    function color3(v4) {
      v4 = v4.dataset.id;
      switch (v4) {
        // top: 103px; left: 210px

        case "black":
          ctx3.fillStyle = '#000000';
          break;

        case "red":
          ctx3.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
          break;

        case "green":
          ctx3.fillStyle = "#009933";
          break;

        case "orange":
          ctx3.fillStyle = "#ff9900";
          break;
      }
      redrawTextsCan3();
    }
```

**Here is HTML code:**

```
<div>
 <select name="change1" onchange="path3(this.value)">
   <option value="left">Left</option>
   <option value="center" selected>Center</option>
   <option value="rightabove">Right Above</option>
   <option value="rightbelow">Right Below</option>
 </select>

 <h3 style="font-size: 15px;padding-top: 0px">Choose Colour</h3>

 <button type="button" class="black" data-id="black" onclick="color3(this)">
 </button>
 <button type="button" class="red" data-id="red" onclick="color3(this)">
 </button>
 <button type="button" class="green" data-id="green" onclick="color3(this)">
 </button>
 <button type="button" class="orange" data-id="orange" onclick="color3(this)"></button>


 <h3 style="font-size: 15px;padding-top: 0px">Number</h3>

 <input id="sourceText3" maxlength="1" type="text" style="height: 32px;width: 223px;">

 <canvas id="canvas3" width="150" height="150" style="position: absolute; top: 113px; left: 400px; z-index: 10;"></canvas>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your font isn't working is because the font source (http://www.miketaylr.com/f/kulminoituva.ttf) is loaded over http, while the jsfiddle is loaded over https. So you get a [Mixed Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content) Error.

I've uploaded that font to GitHub, then used [RawGit](https://rawgit.com) to generate a source link.

```js
 var canvas3 = document.getElementById("canvas3");
        var ctx3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");

        ctx3.font = "90px MyFont";
        ctx3.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx3.textAlign = "center";

        var $text3 = document.getElementById("sourceText3");

        $text3.onkeyup = function(e) {
          redrawTextsCan3();
        }

        function redrawTextsCan3() {
          ctx3.clearRect(0, 0, canvas3.width, canvas3.height);
          wrapText(ctx3, $text3.value, 66.5, 82, "MyFont");
        }

        function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, fontSize, fontFace) {
          var words = text.split(' ');
          var line = '';
          var lineHeight = fontSize;

          context.font = fontSize + " " + fontFace;

          for (var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
            var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
            var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
            var testWidth = metrics.width;
            if (testWidth > maxWidth) {
              context.fillText(line, x, y);
              line = words[n] + ' ';
              y += lineHeight;
            } else {
              line = testLine;
            }
          }
          context.fillText(line, x, y);
          return (y);
        }

        var loc = document.getElementById("canvas3");
        var ctxx = loc.getContext("2d");

        function path3(v2) {
          switch (v2) {
            // top: 103px; left: 210px
            case "rightabove":
              loc.style.top = "93px";
              loc.style.left = "130px";
              loc.style.position = "absolute";
              break;

            case "rightbelow":
              loc.style.top = "133px";
              loc.style.left = "130px";
              loc.style.position = "absolute";
              break;

            case "left":
              loc.style.top = "113px";
              loc.style.left = "400px";
              loc.style.position = "absolute";
              break;

            case "center":
              loc.style.top = "113px";
              loc.style.left = "173px";
              loc.style.position = "absolute";
              break;
          }
          redrawTextsCan3();
        }


        function color3(v4) {
          v4 = v4.dataset.id;
          switch (v4) {
            // top: 103px; left: 210px

            case "black":
              ctx3.fillStyle = '#000000';
              break;

            case "red":
              ctx3.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
              break;

            case "green":
              ctx3.fillStyle = "#009933";
              break;

            case "orange":
              ctx3.fillStyle = "#ff9900";
              break;
          }
          redrawTextsCan3();
        }
```

```css
   #canvas3 {
   border: 2px dotted black;
   border-radius: 5px;
   position: absolute;
 }
 
 #canvas4 {
   border: 2px dotted black;
   border-radius: 5px;
   position: absolute;
 }
 
 .green {
   border: 0.1px solid #CCC;
   margin: 1px;
   zoom: 3;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 22.5px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: #009933;
 }
 
 .green:hover,
 .green:active,
 .green:focus {
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
   opacity: 0.7;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #136a65;
   -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
   transition: all 250ms linear;
 }
 
 .red {
   border: 0.1px solid #CCC;
   margin: 1px;
   zoom: 3;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 22.5px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: #ff0000;
 }
 
 .red:hover,
 .red:active,
 .red:focus {
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
   opacity: 0.7;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #136a65;
   -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
   transition: all 250ms linear;
 }
 
 .black {
   border: 0.1px solid #CCC;
   margin: 1px;
   zoom: 3;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 22.5px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: black;
 }
 
 .black:hover,
 .black:active,
 .black:focus {
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
   opacity: 0.7;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #136a65;
   -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
   transition: all 250ms linear;
 }
 
 .orange {
   border: 0.1px solid #CCC;
   margin: 1px;
   zoom: 3;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   cursor: pointer;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 22.5px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: orange;
 }
 
 .orange:hover,
 .orange:active,
 .orange:focus {
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
   opacity: 0.7;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #136a65;
   -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
   transition: all 250ms linear;
 }

 @font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('https://cdn.rawgit.com/BlazingFire007/Misc/d656d2e6/kulminoituva.ttf');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select name="change1" onchange="path3(this.value)">
    <option value="left">Left</option>
    <option value="center" selected>Center</option>
    <option value="rightabove">Right Above</option>
    <option value="rightbelow">Right Below</option>
  </select>

  <h3 style="font-size: 15px;padding-top: 0px">Choose Colour</h3>

  <button type="button" class="black" data-id="black" onclick="color3(this)"></button>
  <button type="button" class="red" data-id="red" onclick="color3(this)"></button>
  <button type="button" class="green" data-id="green" onclick="color3(this)"></button>
  <button type="button" class="orange" data-id="orange" onclick="color3(this)"></button>


  <h3 style="font-size: 15px;padding-top: 0px">Number</h3>

  <input id="sourceText3" maxlength="2" type="text" style="height: 32px;width: 223px;">

  <canvas id="canvas3" width="150" height="150" style="position: absolute; top: 113px; left: 400px; z-index: 10;"></canvas>

</div>
```

Comment: And that only works cause GitRaw sends back relevant CORS headers for the content: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.
IF the font was hosted on a different domain, which does not return the CORS headers, the font would not be downloaded and thus no visual change.
If used from different domain, you must make server send relevant CORS response headers for the font file - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS